# Delay in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to implement a 1200 millisecond delay after playing a sound in windows phone but the delay is not working.

I am using the following code:

```
bleep.Play(); // play bleep
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1100).Wait();
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage.ItemPage));
```

I was advised not to use System.Threading.

the await function needs to be async and it is causing me some headaches when trying to implement.

Any ideas what else I could use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `await` keyword to wait for the task to complete; `Wait()` should be used rarely, and with extreme caution, because it can make your app appear unresponsive or even cause deadlocks.

```
// 'async' keyword is important!
async Task foo()
{
  bleep.Play(); // play bleep
  await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1100);
  this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage.ItemPage));
}
```

Comment: I would advise to use *async Task* instead of *async void*, unless it's *fire-forget* event.

Comment: @Romasz: Good point. I assumed fire-and-forget since it results in a navigation, but I changed to `Task` anyway

Comment: "Never use `Wait()`" seems too strong to me. Avoid using it and strongly prefer async/await is what I'd say. You really need to be more careful with `Wait()` but sometimes it's really helpful/necessary.

Comment: @yasen true, "never say never" I guess. I updated to say "use with extreme caution."

Answer (score 2):

If you want `synchronous` delay, then you can try:

```
        Thread.Sleep(1200);
        MessageBox.Show("1.2 sec delayed");
```

and in case of `asynchronous` delay, you can use:

```
        Task t = new Task(() => { Thread.Sleep(1200); });
        t.Start();
        MessageBox.Show("1.2 sec delayed");
```

NOTE: Don't forget to add following `namespaces`:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks; // for Task class
using System.Threading; // for Thread class
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is plain wrong. First, `Thread.Sleep()` doesn't even exist in the Portable subset. And your second example wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: I have tested it on windows phone 8 development setup, by the way, I didn't get "Portable subset" ?

Comment: @ Thomas Weller you are correct Thomas Thread.Sleep() does not work in windows 8.1.  I have tried it as well not working.